# Change the data class name in JSON

Tags: c#, json

I need to generate a Json like the one below, with the data class name "Resposta" for each node, so I am using JavaScriptSerializer.

```
{"Status":"1",
"Descricao":"OK",
"Respostas":[
    {"Resposta":
       {
           "Campanha":"353896",
           "Telefone":"71987588216",
           "Data":"20/06/2017 23:40:00",
           "mensagem":"Nao posso falar agora. Envie um SMS."
       }
    },
    {"Resposta":
       {
           "Campanha":"355117",
           "Telefone":"14998538703",
           "Data":"20/06/2017 23:39:00",
           " mensagem ":"Estou dirigindo"
       }
    }
]}
```

My C# classes are:

```
public class retornoRespostas
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public List<Resposta> Respostas { get; set; }
}

public class Resposta
{
    public string Campanha { get; set; }
    public string Telefone { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string mensagem { get; set; }
}
```

The result using my code are:

```
{"Status":"1",
"Descricao":"OK",
"Resposta":[
    {
        "Campanha":"333967",
        "Data":"14/07/2017 11:58:00",
        "Telefone":"21999214958",
        "mensagem":"Nao posso falar agora. Manda um SMS, por favor?"
    },
    {
        "Campanha":"333967",
        "Telefone":"21999214958",
        "Data":"14/07/2017 11:59:00",
        "mensagem":"Nao posso falar agora. Manda um SMS, por favor?"
    }
]}
```

There are another way to put the name "Resposta" to each data class?

Thanks!

Comment: What other way are you looking for?

Comment: You may want to look at [DataContractJsonSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx)

Comment: Dont use `JavaScriptSerializer` it's old and slow. Even Microsoft says Json.NET should be used: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like below should work:

```
public class retornoRespostas
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public List<RespostaWrapper> Respostas { get; set; }
}

public class RespostaWrapper
{
    public Resposta Resposta { get; set; }
}

public class Resposta
{
    public string Campanha { get; set; }
    public string Telefone { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string mensagem { get; set; }
}
```

I would not **recommend** this approach (I prefer your original JSON structure), but it will result in your desired JSON format.